# Как прочитать код?

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] strArr = str.Split(new Char[] { '6', '5'});
        Console.WriteLine(strArr.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First());
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Код берёт данные из переменной `str` и убирает символы переменной, взятые из массива `strArr`.
Что делает этот код и как его прочитать: `(strArr.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First())`

Comment: краткая памятка как читать код: берем название неизвестной функции и ищем к ней документацию. Например, я не знаю, что делает функция ``First()``. Гуглю и узнаю, что она возвращает первый элемент массива. И так далее по всем функциям.

Comment: Почитайте про [Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/linq/), очень мощная штука для работы с коллекциями, если научитесь юзать - то это навсегда останется в сердце и любой другой язык без линка будет казаться урезанным

Comment: чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Split** разбивает строку на массив строк, по какому либо разделителю. В данном случае это символы '6' и '5'.

**OrderByDescending** сортирует по убыванию. ему необходимо передать параметр, в данном случае это длинна строки **s.Length**. **First()** выбирает первый элемент.
Соответственно этот код возвращает самую короткую строку массива:

```
strArr.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First()
```

А вообще, присоединюсь к комментаторам. Читайте документацию по методам и посмотрите что такое Linq, в шарпе используется постоянно

Comment: спасибо, слишком запутанно написано в самом visual studio, и не всегда понятен смысл

Comment: Рад помочь. Если вопрос решен, отметьте ответ как решение